# Geomedia WebMap WFS to vector marker layer in Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, vector, wfs, geomedia, web-mapping

Looking for minimal example/advice on getting a WFS service to show up as a vector layer with markers/icons in Openlayers map.

I have created the WFS service in Geomedia WebMap 6.01.11.19 and the Openlayers map.

a snippet from my map html code:

```
var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("myFeats", {
            minScale: 100000,
            maxScale: 99,
             strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX()],
             protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    version: "1.1.0",
                    srsName: "EPSG:900913",
                    url: "http://gisdev2/OL_WFS/Request.aspx",
                    featureType: ["myFeats"],
                    featurePrefix: "gmgml",
                    featureNS: "http://www.intergraph.com/geomedia/gml",
                    geometryName: "GEOMETRY_PT",
              }),
             renderers: OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers
        }
    );
```

Opening the IE11 debug console it bombs near this line in the Openlayers.js code

{return this.xmldom?"string"==typeof a?this.xmldom.createNode(1,b,a):this.xmldom.createNode(1,b,""):document.createElementNS(a,
b)}

I suspect the problem is with the namespace in the WFS. I have read elsewhere to toggle the checkbox "on" for the 'Feature Collection in WFS namespace' setting in Geomedia WebMap. I have done this. I have also kept the 'Features namespace' value equal to 'http://www.intergraph.com/geomedia/gml' and the 'Features namespace prefix' equal  to 'gmgml'.

Still no luck getting the feature to show in the Openlayers map.

Answer (score 1):

Needed the formatOptions: {xy: false} set for Intergraph WFS + OL

```
var wfs = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("MyFeats", {
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.BBOX(),refresh, 
            clusterStrategy],
            styleMap: styleMap,
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.WFS({
                    version: "1.0.0",
                    srsName: "EPSG:4326",
                    url: "/OL_WFS/Request.aspx",
                    featureType: "MYFEATSVRTCLR_BRGS",
                    featurePrefix: "gmgml",
                    featureNS: "http://www.intergraph.com/geomedia/gml",
                    geometryName: "GEOMETRY_PT",
                    formatOptions: {
                         xy: false
                    }
              }),
             renderers: OpenLayers.Layer.Vector.prototype.renderers
        }
    );
```